# Broken jQuery Accordion in Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to display a jQuery accordion **inside** of a Google Map, I have it working however when I click away from my accordion menu it will not act as an accordion when I re-open it. I'm at a loss as to how to fix it without creating my own accordion from scratch. Any help as to how to make it work properly?

http://mulibraries.missouri.edu/Reference/virtour/demo_fs_mobile.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create these elements again with events too.

I improved your code using `jQuery`, try this:

```
function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {
    var menu_btn = $("<div>");
    menu_btn.attr('id', 'menu_btn');
    menu_btn.attr('title', 'Click to show the Map Navigation');
    menu_btn.html('<b>Menu</b>');
    menu_btn.css({
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        textAlign: 'center',
    });

    $(menu_btn).click(function() {
        $(controlDiv).empty();

        menu_state = 1;

        var menu_nav = $("<div>");
        menu_nav.attr('id', 'menu_nav');
        menu_nav.attr('title', 'Click Map to close Menu');
        menu_nav.css({
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            textAlign: 'center',
        });

        var accordion = $('<div id="accordion"><h3><a href="#">Change Library</a></h3> <div>Ellis<br>Engineering<br>Journalism</div><h3><a href="#">Change Floor</a></h3> <div>Ground Floor<br>First Floor<br>Second Floor<br>Third Floor<br>Fourth Floor<br></div> <h3><a href="#">Change Map</a></h3> <div>Virtual Tour<br>Video Tour<br>Study Rooms<br>Computers</div></div>');

        $(menu_nav).append(accordion);
        $(controlDiv).append(menu_nav);

        $(accordion).accordion({active: 1, autoHeight: false});
    });

    $(controlDiv).empty();
    $(controlDiv).append($(menu_btn).clone(true));

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'click', function() {
        menu_state = 0;

        $(controlDiv).empty();
        $(controlDiv).append($(menu_btn).clone(true));
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed other issues I was having after I got it to work a different way.

Comment: Another issue I'm having though is that the autoHeight is not working (the height should be staying the same) and that the accordion is being placed underneath of the menu button instead of replacing it at the top

Comment: @Raymond it's because margin of the `h3` tag. You can use CSS to remove this margin.